# Condition such that $ax + by = c$ with real coefficients has exactly one integer solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What conditions must $a,b \in \mathbb R$ satisfy in order for $$ax + by = c, \; c \in \mathbb R^*_+$$ to have **exactly** one integer solution $(x_0,y_0)$?

Comment: And which conditions would you impose for $c$?

Comment: @barto See the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we have $c=ax_0+by_0$ and $(a,b)\not=(0,0)$.

If $b=0$, the line $x=c/a$ passes through either no lattice point or infinitely many lattice points.

So, since we have $b\not=0$, we have
$$y-y_0=-\frac{a}{b}(x-x_0).$$
For $x\not=x_0$, we have
$$\frac{y-y_0}{x-x_0}=-\frac{a}{b}.$$
If $-a/b$ is rational, then there exist infinitely many sets of integers $(x,y)$ where $x\not=x_0$. If $-a/b$ is irrational, then there exist no set of integers $(x,y)$ where $x\not=x_0$.

Hence, the condition you want is that $-a/b$ is irrational.

Comment: I had the same idea as you. If the slope of the line is irrational then the line passes through at most one lattice point. but what conditions on a a,b guarantee the existence of exactly one lattice point?

Comment: @Fermat: My answer supposes that $ax_0+by_0=c$. In other words, my answer supposes that a point $(x_0,y_0)$ is given. This is because OP asks the condition only on $a,b$. If OP asked the condition on $a,b,c$ (no lattice point is given), then I think the answer would be that $-a/b$ is irrational and there is a set of integers $(p,q)$ such that $c=ap+bq$. I hope I'm not mistaken:)